# Hadoop getting data error

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to get data from tables using a java program. I added all jars to my project in eclipse but I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000, 
cause: FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException 
                Class com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at hive.HiveQLWhere.main(HiveQLWhere.java:27)
```

Comment: do you have `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found`  in your classpath? which Jar?

Comment: yes exactly ! I added this " hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "

Comment: did you mean hive-**json**-serde.jar -- do you see this class "JSONSerDe" in your jar?

Comment: thank you Sendi for the replay ! I have them both in my referenced libraries but I still have the same error

Comment: np, but now -- I can't guess more .. in eclipse when you to ctrl+t -- and type "JSONSerDe" -- do you see this class ?

Comment: yes I can create instance like this "com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe myclass ;" without any red line

Comment: I resolve it ,just like in creating tables,in reading data also we have to add jar  '../...hive-json-serde.jar;' with the hive command in the terminal and then execute the java program